# children in one to many relation doesn't delete in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity for example called A that has one to many relationship with another entity called B.

A :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<B> getb() {
    return b;
}
```

B:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "sample"))
public A geta() {
    return a;
 }
```

I want to delete all of "b" in "a", so :

```
A a = entityManager.find(A.class, id);
a.getB().clear();
entityManager.merge(a);
```

but child doesn't delete. why ?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: I just changed name for some reason.@JBNizet

Comment: *I get object "a" from DB, then call getB().clear() and finally merge "a" object*: that's not code That's a description of your code. Post the code.

Comment: you're right. I reform. @JBNizet

Comment: Is this code inside a transaction? Do you commit your changes somehow?

Comment: yes, in one transaction. I use spring transaction for transaction managing.@JBNizet

Comment: Then post all this relevant code. How is your class defined? How is it made transactional? Where does the entityManager come from, etc.

Answer (score 1):

try using the entityManager with remove statement:

```
em.remove(getB());
```